# Postgresql Select Rows where associated record with value X or Y does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join, union

I have 3 tables:

```
Table        columns
---------------------
items        id, name
variations   id, item_id
images       id, variation_id, type
```

`image` has a `variation` and `variation` has an `item`

I want to find `items` which don't have `images` of *type* 4 or 5 *(types are any integer 0..5 and cannot be **null**)*

The below query works however it makes use of a **UNION** subquery
with a **NOT IN** constraint which I believe is inefficient - the question is
therefore what is a more efficient way to write this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.name 
FROM items i 
INNER JOIN variations v 
  ON v.item_id = i.id 
INNER JOIN images vi 
  ON vi.variation_id = v.id 
WHERE i.id NOT IN (SELECT i.id FROM items i 
                  INNER JOIN variations v 
                    ON v.item_id = i.id 
                  INNER JOIN images vi 
                    ON vi.variation_id = v.id 
                  WHERE vi.type = 4
                  UNION
                  SELECT i.id FROM items i 
                  INNER JOIN variations v 
                    ON v.item_id = i.id 
                  INNER JOIN images vi 
                    ON vi.variation_id = v.id 
                  WHERE vi.type = 5)
```

---

**Solution**

Based on Gordons answer below final solution is:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from variations v join
                       images im
                       on v.image_id = im.id
                  where v.item_id = i.item_id and i.type in (4, 5)
                 )
and exists (select 1
                  from variations v join
                       images im
                       on v.id = im.variation_id
                       where v.item_id = i.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find items which don't have images of type 4 or 5

Based on your description, this sounds like `not exists`:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from variations v join
                       images im
                       on v.image_id = im.id
                  where v.item_id = i.item_id and i.type in (4, 5)
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, my only issue with this solution is it deviates from the original query results as it includes items that have no images at all - these should be omitted too (description could of been clearer)

Comment: @mb.Brunel . . . There is nothing in your question about that requirement, and I even included the relevant part in the answer.  You can, of course, add an `exists` clause similar to the `not exists` to guarantee that an image exists.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Gordon's answer using aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i.id,
    i.name 
FROM items i 
INNER JOIN variations v 
    ON v.item_id = i.id 
INNER JOIN images vi 
    ON vi.variation_id = v.id
GROUP BY
    i.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE vi.type IN (4, 5)) = 0;
```

Note that the above assumes that `id` be the primary key column in the `items` table.  If not, then maybe we should use `GROUP BY i.id, i.name` instead.

Comment: This solution works however it is slower than the solution using `exists` (tested on 8000 records) execution time  37.935 ms vs 21.742 ms

Comment: @mb.Brunel If you add the appropriate indices, my answer can be made significantly faster.